# Add two different setters for an field using lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I am using @Setter to generate setter but I also want to add one more setter for same field with different datatype as input.

```
@Setter
private Date date;
```

It will generate:

```
public void setDate(Date date) {
  this.date = date;
}
```

I also want to add one more setter where input is of format String.

```
public void setDate(String date) {
  this.date = Date.valueOf(date);
}
```

By using @Setter and adding setDate(String date) setter, lombok is not able to auto generate setDate(Date date) setter. Is there way I can auto generate setter using Date as input and add one more setter explicitly accepting String as input.

Comment: In that case I have to skip Setter for this field. I was using Setter at class level. I have to explicitly add both setters then.

Comment: IDEs are pretty darn good these days at managing getters/setters. I would just manually generate them with your IDE.

Comment: The title should probably be modified to "two polymorphic setters for the same field" instead of "two different setters".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [doc](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html):

> No method is generated if any method already exists with the same name (case insensitive) and same parameter count. For example, getFoo() will not be generated if there's already a method getFoo(String... x) even though it is technically possible to make the method. This caveat exists to prevent confusion. If the generation of a method is skipped for this reason, a warning is emitted instead. Varargs count as 0 to N parameters. You can mark any method with `@lombok.experimental.Tolerate` to hide them from lombok.

My suggestion is to use something like (or use the experimental annotation):

```
@Setter
private Date date;

public void setDateFromString(String date) {
  this.date = Date.valueOf(date);
}
```

Comment: Adding @Tolerate to setter with String as input worked for me. https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/experimental/Tolerate.html:  Put on any method or constructor to make lombok pretend it doesn't exist, i.e., to generate a method which would otherwise be skipped due to possible conflicts.

Comment: @Tolerate indeed works